# Using LINQ with C# in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am stuck on a problem I can't seem to solve. What I want to do is use a Sort lambda on a database by their last names.

EmployeesController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(m.EmployeeGetAll());
    }
```

manager.cs:

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeBase> EmployeeGetAll()
    {
        //use automapper to map objects, source to target
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Employee>, IEnumerable<EmployeeBase>>(ds.Employees);
    }
```

Database value:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

with the above methods it is fine to show a list of all the employees in the db, but where in my controller or methods do i use the lamda? I am basically stuck on if you make a method() in the manager.cs and use lambdas within it to return an object, how do you call this for the index view? As i want when the page loads for the last names to be sorted. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `EmployeeGetAll().OrderBy(x => x.LastName)`

Comment: ah, thank you. Another question... If i want to now display only employees with certain values in one of their columns, say by their store# (ie/ "9") when a user clicks on a link at the top that says store9, how would this be done in that same index()? I don't seem to understand how one Index() method like above will perform multiple lambdas returning different items?

Comment: sorry for being  a bit unclear

Comment: You would have a parameter in your method (say `int? store`) and the after `var query = EmployeeGetAll().OrderBy(x => x.LastName);` use `if (store.HasValue) { query = query.Where(x => x.Store == store); }`

Comment: what would the return statement look like? right now it is: public IEnumerable<TrackBase> TrackGetAll()
        {
          
            return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Track>, IEnumerable<TrackBase>>(ds.Tracks);
        }

Comment: You don't do anything in the method - its named `EmployeeGetAll()` which returns **all** `Employee`. You could always have a separate method named say `FetchByStore(int store)` to return a filtered set, but you may as well just do that in the controller. BUt your now asking different questions in comments which is not acceptable and the current question is unclear and hopefully will be closed soon

Answer (score 0):

I think you should sort  in database level, like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeBase> EmployeeGetAll()
    {
      var all=ds.Employees.OrderBy(e=>e.LastName);
        //use automapper to map objects, source to target
     return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Employee>, IEnumerable<EmployeeBase>>(all);
    }
```

Comment: say I wanted to also have a EmployeeGetAllCanadians() function that filtered employees by countryID. I would have to add a link at the top displayed as "canadian employees".... how would i go about doing that? I am not sure how to return 2 different results in a index() view

Comment: example:public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(m.EmployeeGetAll());
    }

Comment: you have to pass countryId to EmplyeeGetAll like EmployeeGetAll(int? countryId){ var all =ds.Employees.Where(e=>!countryId.HasValue||countryId.Value==e.CountryId).OrderBy(e=>e.LastName);}

Comment: i am still confused of where to place that within the original EmployeeGetAll() method so it calls that when the user clicks on the new link

Comment: or do i just use the other "create" "edit" "delete" methods as where i put it?