# Using LINQ with C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am stuck on a problem implementing LINQ properly on my model. Right now I have it so that when the user clicks on the "list tracks" view they will receive a listing of every song in the DB. What i want to do, is add another link at the top such as "pop tracks" and have it when the user clicks on it, it will sort all the songs by their GenreId (pop) which is 9. I am unsure how to accomplish this as i don't understand how you would return multiple views from 1 index() method (if that's even how i would do it?). Any help is appreciated.

I am now receiving this error:

> xception Details: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type
>   map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Genre -> TrackBase Assignment_3.Models.Genre ->
>   Assignment_3.Controllers.TrackBase
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 74:         { Line 75:             var AllPop = ds.Genres.Where(p
>   => p.GenreId == 9); Line 76:             return mapper.Map>(AllPop); Line 77:         } Line
>   78:

Manager.cs:

```
 public IEnumerable<TrackBase> TrackGetAll()
    {

        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Track>, IEnumerable<TrackBase>>(ds.Tracks);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TrackBase> TrackGetAllPop()
    {
        var AllPop = ds.Genres.Where(p => p.GenreId == 9);
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TrackBase>>(AllPop);
    }
```

TrackController.cs:

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? genreid)
    {
        if (genreid.HasValue && genreid.Value == 9)
        {
            return View(m.TrackGetAllPop());
        }

        return View(m.TrackGetAll());

    }
```

AutoMapperConfig.cs:

```
  cfg.CreateMap<Models.Track, Controllers.TrackBase>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Controllers.TrackBase, Controllers.TracksController>();
```

Comment: Your method needs to be `Index(int? genre)` and you pass the value of genre in the link as a route parameter - `@Html.ActionLink("Pop Tracks", "Index", new { genre = 9 })` (refer the comment to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671386/using-linq-with-c-sharp-in-mvc5)). Then its simply `var tracks = m.TrackGetAll(); if (genre.HasValue) { tracks = tracks.Where(x => x.GenreId =genre); } return View(tracks);`

Comment: You might also want to read [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Now receiving this error above

Comment: That is unrelated to your question (which is about passing a value to the method). You need to spend some time reading the help files to learn how to use this site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the genre id to `Index` action method and filter the songs accordingly. Change your controller to this

```
public ActionResult Index(int? genreid)
{
    if (genreid.HasValue && genreid.Value == 9)
    {
        // return all pop songs to the view
        return View(m.TrackGetAllPop());
    }

    // return all songs to the view
    return View(m.TrackGetAll());
}
```

then in your index

```
@Html.ActionLink("All Tracks", "Index") |
@Html.ActionLink("Pop Tracks", "Index", new { genreid = 9})
```

You also have a problem with `TrackGetAllPop` method

```
public IEnumerable<TrackBase> TrackGetAllPop()
{
    var AllPop = ds.Genres.Where(p => p.GenreId == 9);
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TrackBase>>(AllPop);
}
```

The above method returns `IEnumerable<TrackBase>` but you're querying from `ds.Genres` instead of `ds.Tracks`, so that's why you got the error. Assuming `Track` table has `GenreId` as the foreign key to the `Genre` table, `TrackGetAllPop` method should be like below

```
public IEnumerable<TrackBase> TrackGetAllPop()
{
    var AllPop = ds.Tracks.Where(p => p.GenreId == 9);
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TrackBase>>(AllPop);
}
```

#### More General Solution

The above will work for this particular case, however you can make it more general for other genres too. Add this method in Manager.cs

```
public IEnumerable<TrackBase> TrackGetByGenre(int genreId)
{
    var result = ds.Tracks.Where(p => p.GenreId == genreId);
    return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TrackBase>>(result);
}
```

and change your controller to below

```
public ActionResult Index(int? genreid)
{
    if (genreid.HasValue)
    {
        // return songs based on the passed genreid to the view
        return View(m.TrackGetByGenre(genreid.Value));
    }

    // return all songs to the view
    return View(m.TrackGetAll());
}
```

Comment: See the updated answer. You should've checked that `TrackGetAllPop` method works correctly before even asking this question.